# Unable to find CFNetwork in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

I am trying to use `CFNetwork` in my app so I tried adding `CFNetwork.framework` from the `Edit Target` dialog in Xcode.

The interesting thing is that `CFNetwork` is not visible in the dialog box at all.

Am I missing anything? Do I have to add/install `CFNetwork` in some other way?

Screenshot -
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CFNetwork is part of CoreServices.framework, so you should add CoreServices. The definitive tool to find this out is to use search in Xcode's documentation viewer. (Almost) each documentation page includes the relevant Framework header.